# http status code 404 (Not found)

Tags: relays, error, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup non-exit Tor Relay on ubuntu Server 16.04.1,but I'm getting the following warning:

```
Mar 21 11:37:28.000 [warn] Received http status code 404 (Not found) from x.x.x.x while fetching tor/keys/fp/58......88C
```

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to lookup a relay that *seems* to no longer exist, specifically whatever relay corresponds to the `58......88C` fingerprint.

It's possible that it does still exist, it just wasn't found on the directory provided by `x.x.x.x`.

This error is just a warning, it's not a fatal error and Tor will continue to function normally if it's the only error you've received.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help.How can I check that ,there is some clients that are connected to my relay so that I can be sure that its working?Thank you so much.

Comment: Tor will output a heartbeat to it's logs every few hours to report on statistics, otherwise you can also send it a `SIGUSR1` signal (i.e. run `pkill -SIGUSR1 tor`) to cause it to log the statistics right away or else use a tool like [`arm`](https://www.atagar.com/arm/) to view the current status of the relay.